# Setting mime-type on S3 object

Tags: amazon-s3

Is there a way to have S3 automatically set a mime-type depending on extension? I don't want my uploads to force download if I don't specify a mime-type but rather have the browser decide.

Answer (score 1):

S3 won't do this for you, but most tools and APIs will allow you to specify the MIME type when uploading. Depending on the context you're working with, you should be able to do this relatively easily yourself, and some tools (e.g. Bucket Explorer) will allow you to do mass-assignment of MIME types based on file extension.

Comment: Bucket Explorer isn't a solution. I am uploading with our own POST form. Can you specify mime-types in the direct upload form with maybe a hidden field?

Comment: Ah, I thought you were expecting S3 to detect the MIME type and do something for you. I guess you mean you're using something like this:

http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1434

Note, you can specify the Content-Type as part of that form (the documentation is all there). Hope that helps.